# How to get text only from Wikimedia API? And how to edit CSS?

Tags: css, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

First. How can i edit with CSS this render?
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Albert_Einstein&action=render

Second
I have e link http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exintro=&titles=Stack%20Overflow

RESULT:

```
{"query":{"pages":{"21721040":{"pageid":21721040,"ns":0,"title":"Stack Overflow","extract":"<p><b>Stack Overflow</b> is a website, the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network, created in 2008 by Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky, as a more open alternative to earlier Q&amp;A sites such as Experts Exchange. The name for the website was chosen by voting in April 2008 by readers of <i>Coding Horror</i>, Atwood's popular programming blog.</p>\n<p>It features questions and answers on a wide range of topics in computer programming. The website serves as a platform for users to ask and answer questions, and, through membership and active participation, to vote questions and answers up or down and edit questions and answers in a fashion similar to a wiki or digg. Users of Stack Overflow can earn reputation points and \"badges\"; for example, a person is awarded 10 reputation points for receiving an \"up\" vote on an answer given to a question, and can receive badges for their valued contributions, which represents a kind of gamification of the traditional Q&amp;A site or forum. All user-generated content is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribute-ShareAlike license.</p>\n<p>As of August 2013<sup class=\"plainlinks noprint asof-tag update\" style=\"display:none;\">[update]</sup>, Stack Overflow has over 1,900,000 registered users and more than 5,500,000 questions. Based on the type of tags assigned to questions, the top eight most discussed topics on the site are: C#, Java, PHP, JavaScript, Android, jQuery, C++ and Python.</p>\n<p></p>"}}}}
```

How can i give without this and other charachters?

```
{"query":{"pages":{"21721040":{"pageid":21721040,"ns":0,"title":"Stack Overflow","extract":"
```

Answer (score 0):

That thing you're getting is a JSON object. I'm not really sure how you're trying to use the data, but you should probably parse that JSON and get only that part which is important to you: `extract` property.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answers. I want to get only summary to my Drupal site. I can get texts but there is some code {"query": and etc... How to get just summary text clearly? I tried some combination on Wikipedia Api Sandbox but i can't get without {"query......